# get Database row column value with OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, database-connection, oledbconnection

I have occurred problem in getting my row value, once I read it from Database using `OleDbCommand`

Current code:

```
private static string TryCheckDateTime(OleDbConnection cn, string table, string colName, string dataColumn)
    {
        if (dataColumn.Contains(AllowedValues.String.ToString()))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                OleDbDataReader rowItems;
                // Connection to Database
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                // Query script: "SELECT TOP 5 {0} FROM [DBName].[dbo].[{1}]"
                cmd.CommandText = string.Format(Values.VerifyDatetime, colName, table);
                // Gets top 5 rows
                rowItems = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);

                foreach (var row in rowItems)
                {
                    // how can I get that row data?
                    var a = row;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And value, that I want to get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you tried

```
string test;
while (rowItems.Read())
    test = rowItems[0].ToString();
```

?

Comment: Nope, gives `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

Comment: Excuse me. Try change `foreach` by `string test; while (rowItems.Read()) test = rowItems[0].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help. Use .HasRows first then .Read()

```
  if (rowItems.HasRows)
      {
        rowItems.Read();
              foreach(var row in rowItems)
                {

                    var a = row["sampleonly"].ToString(); // or something
                }
      }
 else
      {
            // do something
      }
```

Comment: Same as Pedro's answer `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`