# C# linked to access database, find row using string instead of integer, and display in messagebox

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have linked my Access database to C# using OleDbAdapter, and cannot figure out how to find a specific row in my database via a string field, rather than a number field. I am making a simple front end UI for a game server manager to find why people are banned or trusted to his server, and need to ensure he can find players via their in game name, rather than an arbitrary ID set by Microsoft. Thanks :)

```
string socialClub1 = socialText.Text;
String connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data" + @" Source=D:\carMeetData.accdb";
String tableName = "Banned";
String query = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", tableName);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    //Open Database Connection
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
    OleDbCommandBuilder cmdB = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
    da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    //Fill the DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, tableName);
    //Close the Database Connection
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Steam: " + ds.Tables["Banned"].Rows[0]["Steam"] + " Social Club: " + ds.Tables["Banned"].Rows[0]["Social Club"]);
}

catch (OleDbException exp)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Database Error:" + exp.Message.ToString());
}

finally
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried and how is it not working?  Currently you don't seem to be filtering the results by any value, string or otherwise.

Comment: `find a specific row in my database via a string field` what do you mean with this? What do you want to find?

Comment: Aleksa - I need to find a specific row in my Access database, using a string (obtained through a textBox in my code) rather than the unique ID. For example, the textBox input is 'qwertyuiop12' and i need to find the row which has that text under the 'Social Club' column, and display that row in a messageBox. Thanks

Comment: David - I have tried putting the input from the textbox into a string variable, and using that to search the database (instead of '1' in the code below) but that produces an error. I cannot think of any way to do this. Thanks     Code: MessageBox.Show("Steam: " + ds.Tables["Banned"].Rows[1]["Steam"] + " Social Club: " + ds.Tables["Banned"].Rows[1]["Social Club"]);

Comment: @Gadget_Man1: Reading the error message would certainly be a good start.  Show the code that you're using *in the question* so we can read and follow it, and explain the specifics about the error.  What is the error message, what are the runtime values when you debug, etc.?

Comment: @David - I don't get an error message per se, but need to know how to search the database using text rather than a number id. The code works at finding a row based on the numeric id, but this is not what my end-user needs. Thanks

Comment: @Gadget_Man1: A `WHERE` clause in SQL (which your code doesn't currently have at all) can indeed use a number, a string, or a variety of conditions to filter the results returned by your query.  This looks like a good place to start familiarizing yourself with it: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-SQL-WHERE-clause-753bbc13-debc-4b28-b527-42eb7885c862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `string socialClub1 = socialText.Text;` is the value you wish to search on then your sql query needs to be `SELECT * FROM Banned where [Social Club] = socialClub1`

You do should not use string concatenation or `String.Format` for this though as it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

OLEDB parameters should use the `?` value instead of the sql server style `@` prefix and are sensitive to the order that they are declared.

Something like this should work:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM Banned where [Social Club] = ?";
var command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("SocialClub", socialText.Text));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @ste-fu, however I am still wondering (as I am new to OleDb and relatively new to C# in general) how to output the result of the command to my MessageBox. Sorry to be a pain, Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261289/get-database-row-column-value-with-oledbcommand

Comment: You're very welcome. If it fixed your issue please accept the answer. (The tick next to the question)